# R data.table performing a unique combination of two list-type columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with two list-type columns, and I cannot figure out how to get a single list column that is the combined list of unique values from both columns.

```r
structure(list(c("ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457"), c("20:49551404:49575092",
"1:169818772:169863100"), list(c("rs2281282", "rs7269297"), c("rs3766154",
"rs17544586", "rs11577641", "rs12116650", "rs9728301")), list(
    structure(c("rs142284790", "rs6096071"), class = "AsIs"),
    structure(c("rs12116650", "rs9728301", "rs11581380"), class = "AsIs"))), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), names = c("GENE", "LOC",
"SNP1", "SNP2"))
```

I have tried a variety of `unique` and `unlist` combinations, but cannot get the merged column.

```r
out[, SNP := unique(unlist(c(.SD))), .SDcols=c("SNP1", "SNP2"), by=out[,.I]]
out[, SNP := unique(unlist(c(SNP1, SNP2)))]
out[, SNP := list(unique(unlist(c(SNP1, SNP2)))), by=out[,.I]]
out[, SNP := lapply(.SD, unique), .SDcols=c("SNP1", "SNP2")]
out[, SNP := lapply(.SD, function(i) unique(unlist(c(i)))), .SDcols=c("SNP1", "SNP2")]
out[, SNP := lapply(.SD, function(i) unique(unlist(c(i)))), .SDcols=c("SNP1", "SNP2"), by=out[,.I]]
```

Edit: I shortened the example. The desired output would be single list column that contains the combination of both columns, without any repeats for a value contained in both columns:

```r
> out[, .(GENE, LOC, SNP)]
              GENE                   LOC
1: ENSG00000000419  20:49551404:49575092
2: ENSG00000000457 1:169818772:169863100
                                                               SNP
1:                       rs2281282,rs7269297,rs142284790,rs6096071
2: rs3766154,rs17544586,rs11577641,rs12116650,rs9728301,rs11581380
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` over each of the lists so that each element of the list can be combined. Using a `union` function ensures that the combination is just the unique elements in each corresponding set of 2 vectors:

```
DT[, SNP := .(Map(union, SNP1, SNP2))]
DT[, .(SNP)]
##                                                               SNP
##                                                            <list>
##1:                       rs2281282,rs7269297,rs142284790,rs6096071
##2: rs3766154,rs17544586,rs11577641,rs12116650,rs9728301,rs11581380
```

Be aware that `union` will remove any duplicate values anywhere, so if you have duplication inside `SNP1` or `SNP2` they will also be removed.